# Parse query, identify field/table usage

Tags: postgresql

Are there some modern Postgres feature that allow auditing which tables and fields are used in SELECTs?

I saw tooling such as Envoy proxy has something about parsing and basic stats, but it seems it falls short of a more complete analysis.

e.g. a table such as:
schema, table, field, selected_times, in_where_clause_times

Comment: It is very unlikely that you will find anything reliable. You would have to parse the query inside PostgreSQL (for example by defining a view on it) and examine the resulting parse tree.

Answer (score 0):

We wrote a library that does just that, to power pganalyze (a Postgres monitoring tool).

The library is called pg_query (Ruby, open-source, MIT licensed), and takes the Postgres parser source code and packages it as a library:

```
PgQuery.parse("SELECT ? FROM x JOIN y USING (id) WHERE z = ?").tables

=> ["x", "y"]

PgQuery.parse("SELECT ? FROM x WHERE x.y = ? AND z = ?").filter_columns

=> [["x", "y"], [nil, "z"]]
```

See https://github.com/pganalyze/pg_query#extracting-tables-from-a-query and https://pganalyze.com/blog/pg-query-2-0-postgres-query-parser for more context. There are also wrappers around the core parser in other languages, but not all have the tables/filter_columns helpers.

Note that this is based on the raw parser, i.e. you need to interpret which tables this refers to (e.g. if you have different schemas and set a search_path, etc).